# Listener from activity to fragment, when there is a listener from the fragment to the activity yet

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, listener

I have an activity calls Activity A, and fragment calls Fragment B.
In activity A I was implement a listener of Fragment B.
now, I want to implement a listener of activity A in fragment B and it doesn't work for me...
I understand this is a circular dependencies, but how can I do it?

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment{

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

 public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void Add(Item Item);
   }
 }
```

the activity:

```
public class ActivityA extends implements
    FragmentB.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
}
```

Comment: Create an own file for the interface so it's not an inner interface.

Comment: create file that implement both?